# The caplock seemed to be on for data entry

Tags: internet-explorer-9

Last night my wife was in a textbox on a web page, trying to enter the captcha (?sp) word.  It always made whatever she typed in upper case, which was very irritating.  But only in that textbox.  And when I brought up Notepad and typed the same thing, it typed in lower case.  What would cause that behavior?  Is there a way for us to turn it off?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without knowing which Captcha service was being used it is difficult to say, but there are lots of ways to programmatically make something all caps. Javascript, which is common in web pages, has a method called toUpper() which could do what you indicated.

I guess the point is that is probably wasn't your computer, your browser, your keyboard, or your wife causing it to happen.

Comment: Almost certainly Javascript. If it is, the only way to turn it off would be to turn off Javascript.

Comment: @Amazed, in Firefox you could use the Greasemonkey plugin and selectively disable just that bit of JavaScript. (The OP did specifidy IE9.)

Comment: @CarlF Yes, that's true. There is a Greasemonkey version for IE, but I don't know if it's a direct port, independent project, etc. of the original or whether its functionality is substantially similar.

Answer (score 4):

> What would cause that behavior?

Most likely it is done using JavaScript, which can be as simple as:

```
<input type="text"
       onchange="this.value = this.value.toUpper()"
       onkeypress="this.value = this.value.toUpper()">
```

---

> Is there a way for us to turn it off?

Do you need to?

If you are only supposed to type upper-case letters in a text box, what's the harm if they automatically become upper-case? It's not like the website prevents you from simply typing in the usual way (holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>).

No, you cannot turn it off without disabling JavaScript entirely – which would break way too many websites. (In IE, this is done through [*Internet Options → Security → Zones*](http://browsers.about.com/od/internetexplorertutorials/ss/disable-javascript-ie9.htm).)